# Buy bitcoins with my regular AMEX (american express card)

Tags: buy-bitcoins, american-express

I can not find any website or service to buy bitcoins with my AMEX.
www.bctquick.com does not work aymore ? (webpage inactive)

any advise ?

Comment: Due to the high risk of fraud you will find it very difficult to locate such a service.

Comment: On a related note, Circle.com allows purchases with Visa or Mastercard, but not AMEX.

Answer (score 0):

You can try virwox.com but it will also depend on the country that you choose for sign up. I know that when you use Germany as the country for sign up, you can pay with AMEX but you will have to covert to SLL first before you can get the bitcoins. I hope this helps eventhough you asked this question long ago!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Coinbase](http://www.coinbase.com) . There many scenarios to buy bitcoins

1. make a bank transfer to a given bank account
2. User credit card which suppot 3D secure ( I suppose AMEX supports 3D secure technology)

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

U can use this platform http://www.ecoin.eu . I think it's a better option. And it's without any commissions. Good luck!

Comment: When recommending a service, please elaborate: Why is it a better option? How are you qualified to judge it? Why do you recommend it? What is your relationship to the service provider? Posts that fail to reinforce their recommendation in such a fashion tend to be voted as spam and/or deleted.

Comment: 'cause I am trading on it, it's better 'cause it the 1st platform without any commissions and free arbitrage service